# parse xml with C# using xdocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have one very odd and strange xml(which is not my fault) and i want to get some info from it with c# and linq. XML is:

```
<Match BeginTime="2012-05-16T13:21:56.6737546+02:00" EndTime="2012-05-16T13:24:04.3994176+02:00" Winner="2">

  <Period Number="1" MaximumDuration="PT2M" BeginTime="2012-05-16T13:21:56.6737546+02:00" 
    EndTime="2012-05-16T13:22:25.3952338+02:00" MatchDuration="PT2M" Winner="2">
    <Point Competitor="1" Value="1" MatchTime="PT6.5178048S" Time="2012-05-16T13:22:03.6018269+02:00" />
    <Point Competitor="2" Value="2" MatchTime="PT1M57S" Time="2012-05-16T13:22:21.4017106+02:00" />
  </Period>

  <Pause MaximumDuration="PT30S" AutomaticallyStartTime="true" BeginTime="2012-05-16T13:22:25.3952338+02:00" 
    EndTime="2012-05-16T13:22:36.1092608+02:00" />
  <Period Number="2" MaximumDuration="PT2M" BeginTime="2012-05-16T13:22:37.2592378+02:00"
     EndTime="2012-05-16T13:23:33.0777937+02:00" MatchDuration="PT2M" Winner="2">
    <Point Competitor="2" Value="3" MatchTime="PT10.2121084S" Time="2012-05-16T13:22:47.4932385+02:00" />
    <Point Competitor="1" Value="2" MatchTime="PT15.2950443S" Time="2012-05-16T13:22:52.5951376+02:00" />
    <Point Competitor="2" Value="2" MatchTime="PT41.1295728S" Time="2012-05-16T13:23:18.3988393+02:00" />
  </Period>
  <Pause MaximumDuration="PT30S" AutomaticallyStartTime="true" BeginTime="2012-05-16T13:23:33.0777937+02:00" />
  <Period Number="3" MaximumDuration="PT2M" />
</Match>
```

As you can see i have 3 periods and in each period i have competitor number which is 1 or 2 and point for each competitor whic are in "Value", but in one period i can have more points("Values") for one competitor so i have to sum ti somehow, i am strugling with this one so any advice or help anyone?

Comment: Gives us more of your XML so we have a better clue.

Comment: There's a reason that there's a preview - so you can see what you're going to post..

Comment: i am putting xml but it's not showing all

Comment: my question should be how to put xml in my question on SO :-)
well i don't know how

Comment: @GoranB You need to indent your xml with 4 spaces to make it show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample XML

```
  <root>
      <ul class="connectedSortable ui-sortable" tid="1146">
        <li class="termName">Fall 2010</li>
        <li class="course" cid="2826" style="">FAC101: Art Appreciation</li>
        <li class="course" cid="2827" style="">CSC105: Using Modern Operating Systems</li>
        <li class="course" cid="2828" style="">CSC110: Introduction to Computer Science</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="connectedSortable ui-sortable" tid="1156">
        <li class="termName">Winter 2011</li>
        <li class="course" cid="2829" style="">FAC105: Leadership and Problem Solving</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="connectedSortable ui-sortable" tid="1159">
        <li class="termName">Spring 2011</li>
      </ul>
    </root>
```

reading with C#

```
var reader = new StringReader(termsXml);
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader);

var terms = from term in xdoc.Descendants("ul")
            select new
            {
                TermId = term.Attribute("tid").Value,
                Courses = term.Descendants("li")
            };

foreach (var term in terms)
{
    var courseIds = (from course in term.Courses
                        where course.Attribute("cid") != null
                        select course.Attribute("cid").Value).ToList();

    // do stuff with the courseids here

}
```

Comment: Thank you, i have used your code with little modification and it works!